# Bridging of Internal Network in KVM

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, bridge

I am working on a project regarding deployment of VMs as internal network, which should be accessible from external LAN, in KVM. I am stuck in bridging these virtual machines. My setup consists of three VMs which I will reference as vm0, vm1 and vm2
vm0 has four NICs.

1. First and Second are connected to eth0 and eth1, the physical NICs
   of host through bridges.
2. Third and Fourth are connected with vm1 and vm2.
   [This is the taxonomy I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2g3J.jpg)

I am unable so far to configure the second part. When I choose Network Interfaces in vm1 or vm2, it does not provide any option to connect directly to the third and fourth NICs of vm0. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect these VMs directly to one another. If you want them to be on an isolated virtual network, created a NAT network (or use libvirt's default network), assign all the private network based NICs to that network, and give them IPs that will be able to ping each other.